# Upgrading to Ubuntu Pro. Where is the token?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-pro

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it will expire in 4/23. I'd like to upgrade my workstation to Ubuntu Pro workstation, no support. The instructions say to run:

```
sudo ua attach TOKEN
```

But where do I get the token? I can't find it in Ubuntu One. I also looked in LivePatch (same thing?).

Answer (score 3):

Your account at https://ubuntu.com/pro is where you see your subscriptions and your tokens.