# No Code - Ubuntu Pro on 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-pro

I just purchased Ubuntu Pro for my 20.04 LTS desktop. When I go to the Software & Updates -> Enable Ubuntu Pro -> Enter code on ubuntu.com/pro/attach, there is no code shown.

Has anybody seen this issue? I also tried to enter the token but it failed with Invalid token.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are completely sure that you did not make a typo, then seek technical and account assistance with Ubuntu Pro directly from Canonical. AskUbuntu volunteers have no special insight into the proprietary Ubuntu Pro product. Try the "Contact Us" link at https://ubuntu.com/support or open a topic in the [Pro section of Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/ubuntu-pro/116).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [upgrading to ubuntu pro. Where is the token?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451961/upgrading-to-ubuntu-pro-where-is-the-token)

Comment: @karel - Thanks but no, the command line `sudo pro attach <token>` fails with `Failed to attach machine`. I've opened a ticket with `canonical`.

Comment: [update] My issue appears to be a TLS issue related to local isuer certificate (certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131))

Answer (score 0):

Open https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard
Go to "Your Subscriptions" and get the token.

[image]

Then, open a terminal, and enter the command

```
sudo pro attach your-token-number
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried that and I get "Failed to attach machine. See https://ubuntu.com/pro" .

Comment: FYI any errors from using `pro attach <token>` will be output to `/var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log`.